# DOORS DXL. How to put each word in a string into separate strings

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to put each word in a string into a separate string. So if my string has a list of words like, "John, Mary, Barbara" and the words are separate by a carriage return (not a comma as shown in the example), how do I put John into one string, Mary into another string and Barbara into a third string. The strings are not created so I will have to create them on the fly and that is ok. This is what I have tried:

```
for (n; n<100; n++){
    s1 = s[n:n]
    if(s1 == "\n") {
        break
    }
}
```

Since I want this separation to occur for every object (a specific column in a module) I will have to put whatever the correct code is into a loop like "for o in m do{ }.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these functions would help. However, you would have to get familiar with the `Skip` type (the DXL manual helps with that).

`stringSplit()` divides `str` into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array (`Skip` type) of these substrings. If pattern is a *String*, then its contents are used as the delimiter when splitting str. If pattern is *empty* or *null*, the value of a single space is used. If pattern is a *single space*, `str` is split on whitespace, with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace characters ignored.

```
Skip stringSplit(string str, string pattern) {

    if (null str) return null
    
    if (null(pattern) || 0 == length(pattern))
        pattern = " ";
    
    Skip result = create;
    int i = 0; // index for searching in str
    int j = 0; // index counter for result array
    bool found = true;

    while (found) {
        // find pattern     
        int pos = 0;
        int len = 0;

        found = findPlainText(str[i:], pattern, pos, len, true);
        
        if (found) {
            // insert into result
            put(result, j++, str[i:i+pos-1]);
            i += pos + len;
        }
    }
    // append the rest after last found pattern
    put(result, j, str[i:]);

    return result;
}
```

You might prefer to remove the commas first since the last word is not followed by a comma.

`stringWipe()` returns a copy of `str` with all occurrences of characters in `chars` eliminated:

```
string stringWipe(string str, string chars) {
    
    if (null str) return str

    int lenStr = length str
    if (lenStr == 0) return str
    
    int lenChars = length(chars);
    if (lenChars == 0) return str 

    Buffer buf = create
    int i
    for (i=0; i<lenStr; i++) {
        
        char c = str[i]
        bool skip = false
        int j
        for (j=0; j<lenChars; j++) {
            
           if (c == chars[j]) { 
                skip = true
                break
            }
        }

        if (skip)
            continue

        buf += c
    }
    
    string result = stringOf(buf);
    delete buf
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thank you Twonky. This is certainly more difficult and complex than I though and my DXL skill level. I may have to contract the complete task out as this string issue is just a part of a larger task. But thank you for giving me this code to work on and learn, even though I don't understand the reasons for some of the code.

Comment: @HamNaz: If you think the answer is useful, you might want to consider to accept it. That's how things work here at StackOverflow.